# Display column from empty column (fixed width and space delimited) in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have log file (in txt) with the following text

```
UNIT       PHYS STATE LOCATION              INFO
TCSM-1098       SE-NH                        -                            
ETPE-5-0   1403 SE-OU              BCSU-1   ACTV FLTY                     
ETIP-6     1402 SE-NH                        -
```

They r delimited by space...
How am I acquired the output like below?

```
UNIT|PHYS|STATE|LOCATION|INFO
TCSM-1098||SE-NH||-                            
ETPE-5-0|1403|SE-OU|BCSU-1|ACTV FLTY                     
ETIP-6|1402|SE-NH||-
```

Thank in advance

This is what I've tried so far

```
cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" } {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' | sed 's/ /|/g'
```

It produces output like this

```
|UNIT|PHYS|STATE|LOCATION|INFO|
|TCSM-1098|SE-NH|-|
|ETPE-5-0|1403|SE-OU|BCSU-1|ACTV|FLTY
|ETIP-6|1402|SE-NH|-|
```

The column isn't excatly like what I hope for

Comment: cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[[:space:]][[:space:]]+" } {print $1,$2,$3,$4}' | sed 's/ /|/g'

Comment: I was confused by this line `TCSM-1098||SE-NH||-` How can a script recognize that some space between 1st and 2nd field should become an empty field???

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Thats the problem, Im trying to acquire that

Comment: @123: If the input is in a fixed-width format, it should be possible. Check my solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it's not delimited but fixed-width format.

```
$ perl -ple '
    $_ = join "|", 
        map {s/^\s+|\s+$//g;$_}
        unpack ("a11 a5 a6 a22 a30",$_);
'  <file.txt
```

how it works

- -p switch : loop over input lines (default var: $_) and print it
- -l switch : chomp line ending (\n) and add it to output
- -e : inline command
- unpack function : takes defined format and input line and returns an array
- map function : apply block to each element of array: regex to remove heading trailing spaces
- join function : takes delimiter and array and gives string
- $_ = : affects the string to default var for output

Comment: It worked! Would u like to explain a little about the script?

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -wE 'my @lengths;
          $_ = <>;
          push @lengths, length $1 while /(\S+\s*)/g;
          $lengths[-1] = "*";
          my $f;
          say join  "|",
              map s/^\s+|\s+$//gr,
              unpack "A" . join("A", @lengths), $_
          while (!$f++ or $_ = <>);' -- infile
```

The format is not whitespace separated, it's a fixed-width.

The @lengths array will be populated by the widths of the columns taken from the first line of the input. The last column width is replaced with `*`, as its width can't be deduced from the header.

Then, an [unpack](http://p3rl.org/unpack) template is created from the lengths that's used to parse the file.

`$f` is just a flag that makes it possible to apply the template to the header line itself.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for FIELDWITDHS to handle fixed-width fields:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='11 5 6 22 99' -v OFS='|' '{$1=$1; gsub(/ *\| */,"|"); sub(/ +$/,"")}1' file
UNIT|PHYS|STATE|LOCATION|INFO
TCSM-1098||SE-NH||-
ETPE-5-0|1403|SE-OU|BCSU-1|ACTV FLTY
ETIP-6|1402|SE-NH||-
```

I think it's pretty clear and self-explanatory but let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Manually, in `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{split("11 5 6 23 99", cols); } 
    {s=0; 
     for (i in cols) {
        field = substr($0, s, cols[i]); 
        s += cols[i]; 
        sub(/^ */, "", field);
        sub(/ *$/, "", field); 
        printf "%s|", field;  
     }; 
     printf "\n" } ' file
UNIT|PHYS|STATE|LOCATION|INFO|
TCSM-1098||SE-NH||-|
ETPE-5-0|1403|SE-OU|BCSU-1|ACTV FLTY|
ETIP-6|1402|SE-NH||-|
```

The widths of the columns are set in the `BEGIN` block, then for each line we take substrings of the line of the required length. `s` counts the starting position of the current column, the `sub()` calls remove leading and trailing spaces. The code as such prints a trailing `|` on each line, but that can be worked around by making the first or last column a special case.

Note that the last field is not like in your output, it's hard to tell where the split between `ACTV` and `FLTY` should be. Is that fixed width too, or is the space a separator there?